# How to calculate the residuals of ARIMA-GARCH model?

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

For some reason, I need to calculate residuals of a fitted ARMA-GARCH model manually, but found that the calculated residuals are different of those directly from the R package such `rugarch`. I put the estimated parameters back to the model and use the training data to back out the residuals. How to get the staring residuals at $t=0$, $t=-1$ etc. Should I treat the fitted ARMA-GARCH just as a fitted ARMA model?

Comment: Are you trying to compute the standardised residuals or the unstandardised residuals? In case you do not have a model for the mean, the unstandardised residuals are the same as your modelled time series. Else, you should first establish that you are able to compute the fitted variance correctly, prior to computing the residuals. In order to understand the possible pitfalls of computing these, please elaborate on the variance model that you are trying to fit using `rugarch`. Having access to (a sample of) your data as well as the code being used would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, tchakravarty for the kind response. I have a fitted ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model and want to calculate the unstandardized residuals. Based on my understanding of your comments, should I just ignore the GARCH(1, 1) part and use the ARMA(1,1) to get the residuals? Yes, for sure, if I need the standardized residuals, I should consider the GARCH(1,1) part.

Comment: That is right - to get the unstandardised residuals, simply demean your time series using the conditional mean prediction.

Comment: Thanks, tchakravarty. In this case, ARMA and ARMA-GARCH models are the same in case of obtaining unstandardized residuals.